# Angular 7 pdf-viewer not displaying pdf file

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

in my project I get files from Amazon. File always uploads successfully from Amazon, but not always displayed, and when not displayed in my console I see this warning

```
Warning: Name token is longer than allowed by the spec: 148
Warning: Name token is longer than allowed by the spec: 204
Warning: Name token is longer than allowed by the spec: 148
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
```

Code looks like this

```
      <div class="files-list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let file of files">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <pdf-viewer *ngIf="file['file_path']"
                          [page]="1"
                          [src]="file['file_path']"
                          [show-all]="false"
                          [original-size]="false"
                          [show-borders]="true"
                          style="display: block; height: 210px"
              ></pdf-viewer>
              <span class="file-name" *ngIf="file.type === 'application/pdf'">{{ file?.name }}</span>
              <span class="file-name" *ngIf="file.type !== 'application/pdf'">{{ file?.name.slice(11) }}</span>
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And I can't understand why sometimes file are displayed and sometimes not, and if I supply a static url instead of that, then the file is always displayed **file['file_path']**.
Who realties can say that I'm not doing it right, thanks in advance.

Comment: What NPM package you're using for PDF viewer?

Comment: "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0"

Comment: Have you tried to view it with simple Iframe? just for debugging `<iframe type="application/pdf" width='100%' height='500' [src]='pdfdatauristring | safe'></iframe>`

Comment: @VladKostyukevich no, I wanted to understand why pdf-viewer does not work